# oauth2client with django flowfield

Tags: django, oauth, google-api

Now that I got back to my googleapi django project, I found out that oauth2client no longer uses the flowfield class, and has a couple directory changes. By that, I mean the update from oauth2client 2.0.0 to oauth2client 3.0.0. I can probably cover the directory changes, but is there an alternative to the removal of flowfield?

Answer (score 3):

if you are using the latest version of django, you can use oauth2client v 2.2.0

This has a fix for django 1.10 as well and works fine.

https://github.com/google/oauth2client/commit/a3cbf51bc9dcb9494bb657ac5bc1749a80bc2973